# Getting failure callback for Producer in rabbitmq when back pressure kicks in

Tags: rabbitmq, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I wanted to find out the failed messages for my rabbitmq producers using some call back api.I have configured rabbitmq with [{rabbit, [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.001}]}]. and tried pushing lot of messages but all the messages are getting accepted and TimeoutException is coming later on and messages not getting send to Queue`enter code here`, Please tell me how to capture it.

Code for sending message:

```
// #create-sink - producer
        final Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<Done>> amqpSink =
            AmqpSink.createSimple(
                AmqpSinkSettings.create(connectionProvider)
                    .withRoutingKey(AkkaConstants.queueName)
                    .withDeclaration(queueDeclaration));


        // #run-sink
        //final List<String> input = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
        //Source.from(input).map(ByteString::fromString).runWith(amqpSink, materializer);

        String filePath = "D:\\subrata\\code\\akkaAmqpTest-master\\akkaAmqpTest-master\\logs2\\dummy.txt";
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);

        // List containing 78198 individual message
        List<String> contents = Files.readAllLines(path);
        System.out.println("********** file reading done ....");
        int times = 5;

        // Send 78198*times message to Queue [From console i can see 400000 number of messages being sent]
        for(int i=0;i<times;i++) {
            Source.from(contents).map(ByteString::fromString).runWith(amqpSink, materializer);
        }
        System.out.println("************* sending to queue is done");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately currently that is not supported out of the box. Ideally the producer would be modeled as a `Flow` which would send all incoming messages to the AMQP broker and would emit the same message with a result weather it has been successfully sent to the broker or not. There is [a ticket to track this possible improvement](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/1132) on the Alpakka issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But is there any way i can test back pressure feature of rabbitmq.

Source.from(contents)
               .buffer(10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure())
         .map(ByteString::fromString)
         .runWith(amqpSink, materializer)
I was trying the above for various testing from producer side.

Comment: Take a look at [the `conflate` operator](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/conflate.html#conflate) which allows faster upstream to continue even if the slower downstream (RabbitMQ in your case) is backpressuring. In that case `conflate` will start to summarize incoming messages and when RabbitMQ starts consuming again, it will get the summary, from which it will be evident that backpressure was kicked in.

Comment: Can we get notification for blocked listener when provider connection are blocked. Using ConnectionFactory we can get the connection and it has addBlockedListener but none of the AmqpDetailsConnectionProvider gives any call back api for memory full ? Plz help...

Comment: It could be possible to expose the ability to add blocked listener to the connection factory. But what is your use-case? What would you like to do from the blocked callback?

Comment: If the connection is blocked and then i can stop sending next set of messages temporarily and when i start getting unblocked callback then i can resume it... Thinking about the use cases when i reach max memory limit etc

Comment: Where do the messages come from? If the source of the messages is Akka Stream Source or Reactive Streams publisher then this is automatically handled by backpressure.